An out of bounds error occurred in the drawing of QCAradar
Problem：

Error in value[[jvseq[[jjj]]]]：subscript out of bounds

This is my code:
ZZJ<-minimize(ZZB,
              include = "?",
              details = TRUE,
              show.cases = TRUE,
              dir.exp = c("1,0,-"))
ZZJ
#提取简单解
ZZJ$i.sol$C1P1$p.sol

QCAradar(results = ZZJ, outcome = "Y1", fit = TRE, sol = "c1p1i1")


I tried to change sol to null, but it didn't work

QCAradar(results = ZZJ, outcome = "Y1", fit = TRE, sol = "c1p1i1")
the problem in this text

Thank you very much for your viewing guidance
